# Set attributes to be unsafe by default

Tags: yii, model, attributes, default

I have a model containing the following

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5', 'length'),

        // Search Scenario
        array('attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

        // Scenario x
        array('attr1, attr2, attr3', 'safe', 'on' => 'x'),
        //array('attr1, attr2, attr3', 'unsafe', 'on' => 'y'),

        // Scenario y
        array('attr4, attr5', 'safe', 'on' => 'y'),
        //array('attr4, attr5', 'unsafe', 'on' => 'x'),
    );
}
```

When I try masive assignment on scenario `x`, it doesn't reject the unsafe attributes (`attr4` and `attr5`) unless I uncomment the unsafe rules.

Is it possible to set all attribute to be unsafe by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split this rule into two:

```
    array('attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5', 'length'),
```

into:

```
    array('attr1, attr2, attr3', 'length'),
    array('attr4, attr5', 'length', 'on' => 'y'),
```

Remove these current rules (not needed):

```
    array('attr1, attr2, attr3', 'safe', 'on' => 'x'),
    array('attr4, attr5', 'safe', 'on' => 'y'),
```